# Calling Scala from Groovy: How to handle different collection types?

Tags: scala, interop, groovy

I'm using **Groovy for testing** and **Scala for actual code**. Obviously I often use Scala's collection types - but when I generate test data in Groovy I often use the java.util.*-types.

I started writing static conversion methods based on the [scalaj-collection](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-collection) library. But that's just not 'groovy'.

**What's the best approach to convert one to the other? 
Might implicit conversions work somehow?**

**UPDATE:**

For example if I wouldn't manually convert the types I of course get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: static setup is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList)
    Possible solutions: setup(scala.collection.immutable.List)
```

Comment: Mh, I would be interested why you use Groovy instead of Scala for testing...

Comment: For me there are 2 reasons: 1) In IntelliJ it takes much longer to compile a (quite) big project based on Scala when the tests are in Scala as well and 2) the best BDD framework I know 'Spock' is based on Groovy and I don't know any Scala BDD testing framework that is as simple and great as this one (no, not even Specs, Spock is amazingly simple and concise)

Comment: Did you make any progress on this topic in the recent years?

Comment: @jhunovis yes, by abandoning the idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the "built-in" implicit conversions?

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

Comment: I call a Scala method from Groovy - when I do this and the types don't match I simply get a "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static setup is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) - Possible solutions: setup(scala.collection.immutable.List)"

As I see it the implicit conversions can't possibly work this way..

Comment: You can still call the conversions provided there "manually".

Comment: Well, that's what I'm already doing [I started writing static conversion methods] - I was wondering if there is an easier way? Having to wrap every single argument with list()/array()/map() makes the code pretty bloated. I'm not familiar with all of Groovy's capabilities - I thought it might have something "like" implicit conversions as well.

Comment: By the way, when using the methods in JavaConversions for some reason Scala 'calls my bluff' and says: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.JavaConversions$JMapWrapper cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to change your Scala code to use Java collection types when declaring parameters and rely on implicit conversions in the method body to get the benefit of Scala collections operations.